# How to align two different pictures in such a way, that they match as close as possible?

Tags: image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I need to automatically align an image **B** on top of another image **A** in such a way, that the contents of the image match as good as possible.

The images can be shifted in x/y directions and rotated up to 5 degrees on z, but they won't be distorted (i.e. scaled or keystoned).

Maybe someone can recommend some good links or books on this topic, or share some thoughts how such an alignment of images could be done.

If there wasn't the rotation problem, then I could simply try to compare rows of pixels with a brute-force method until I find a match, and then I know the offset and can align the image.

Do I need AI for this?

I'm having a hard time finding resources on image processing which go into detail how these alignment-algorithms work.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but I think it might be helpful if you clarify what you mean by "as good as possible" -- "good" in what sense?

Comment: an interesting question! in addition to @Mehrdad's request for your specification of 'good,' how many images will you be aligning / what sort of running time do you expect?

Comment: @BugAlert: Furthermore, are the images guaranteed to be exactly alignable (e.g. are they guaranteed to be identical but only linearly transformed), or are they only "similar" in some respects (e.g. can they differ by artifacts, etc.)?

Comment: @BugAlert: The keyword to search for is "image registration."  There are several libraries out there, and lots of information online.

Comment: [Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), which can be quite efficiently implemented with the [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_fourier_transform), can be used to detect how much one picture must be shifted (in x/y direction) in order to match another picture as closely as possible. Since it does not require an exact match, and the angle limit is only 5 degrees, maybe it is sufficient - otherwise, you could run several iterations with e.g. 1 degree increments.

Comment: It's far easier to fix the rotation first. Basically, you first run an edge detection algorithm on both images, and a 1D convolution  on the distribution of directions of those edges. This doesn't require an x/y alignment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So what people often do in this case is first find points in the images that match then compute the best transformation matrix with least squares.  The point matching is not particularly simple and often times you just use human input for this task, you have to do it all the time for calibrating cameras.  Anyway, if you want to fully automate this process you can use [feature extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction#Image_processing) techniques to find matching points, there are volumes of research papers written on this topic and any [standard computer vision text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130851981) will have a chapter on this.  Once you have N matching points, solving for the least squares transformation matrix is pretty straightforward and, again, can be found in any computer vision text, so I'll assume you got that covered.

If you don't want to find point correspondences you could directly optimize the rotation and translation using steepest descent, trouble is this is non-convex so there are no guarantees you will find the correct transformation.  You could do random restarts or simulated annealing or any other global optimization tricks on top of this, that would most likely work.  I can't find any references to this problem, but it's basically a digital image stabilization algorithm I had to implement it when I took computer vision but that was many years ago, [here are the relevant slides](http://ugweb.cs.ualberta.ca/~vis/courses/gradCompVis12/) though, look at "stabilization revisited". Yes, I know those slides are terrible, I didn't make them :)  However, the method for determining the gradient is quite an elegant one, since finite difference is clearly intractable.

Edit:  I finally found the paper that went over how to do this [here](http://www.ri.cmu.edu/publication_view.html?pub_id=4031), it's a really great paper and it explains the Lucas-Kanade algorithm very nicely.  Also, [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImgAlign2.aspx?display=Print) has a whole lot of material and source code on image alignment that will probably be useful.

Comment: The last link is broken. Keen to see what site it is

Answer (score 0):

for aligning the 2 images together you have to carry out image registration technique.
In matlab, write functions for image registration and select your desirable features for reference called 'feature points' using 'control point selection tool' to register images.
Read more about image registration in the matlab help window to understand properly.